# Passing parameter from component to controller through ActionFunction

Tags: apex, controller, visualforce-component, parameters

I would like to pass a parameter from my component to the controller.
Here is the source code:

```
    <apex:actionFunction name="attachFil" action="{!attachFile}">
    <apex:param name="myImageURL" assignTo="{!pictureurl}" value=""/>
    </apex:actionFunction>

     <Script>attachFil('ok!!!');</script>
```

The controller have a field named **pictureurl**, and a function named  **attachFile**.
When I debug in the controller attachFile function, I find the pictureurl = null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `rerender` param to the `actionFunction`. This is a quirk of actionFunctions and has been around a while.

the `rerender` param can be anything - eg `rerender="nothing"` or `rerender=""` and it should work.

Also, make sure your variable that you are passing is public and has a setter, eg
`public String pictureurl {get; set;}`